# Cloud functions install package from private git repo

Tags: git, npm, google-cloud-functions

So I have all my shared npm packages in separate git repositories.

I can use one of them in another repo by using `npm install git:url/to/repository`.

Now I need to create a Google cloud function.

How do I add my private git URL as a dependency?

Is there some file I can use to specify git credentials, and some way of getting those from an environment variable so I don't have to hardcode them (for security reasons)?

If not, I'll have to install them locally or in CI and upload the `node_modules` directory along everything else, which is fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use private repository. You have to embed your lib with your code when you deploy.
Or, if you can use http trigger, have a look to [cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) you can package your container and thus do what you want at build phase.